# Copy attribute value to clipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, copy-paste

I already have it set up to where the page URL dynamically becomes the value of `href` (I can change the attribute or add one if needed). How can I make the link copy the `href` value to the clipboard?

I'm not looking for how to copy text from some other element by calling on it's `id` or `class`, I'm trying to make the link copy the text from the attribute in itself.

```
<li><a href='page.url'><i class='material-icons'>content_copy</i></a></li>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't recommend rolling out your own solution due to browser support quirks, however, there's a fully tested and trusted small 2 file library that already solves this problem (almost 20k stars on GitHub) [clipboard.js](https://github.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js) that you should consider using, hope this helped you out.

Comment: All I had to do was add the `data-clipboard-text` attribute.

Comment: yeh it's really simple and nice solution